# Conversion error in cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, cursor

I keep getting this error when I run a simple update statement.

> Msg 16922, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TRG_MEM_BALANCE_AWW, Line 72
>   Cursor Fetch: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to decimal is not allowed.

This is my code that I have for my trigger. I don't see what is being converted incorrectly?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_MEM_BALANCE_AWW]
ON [dbo].[DETAILRENTAL]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) 
       AND
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE CURSORFORUPDATE CURSOR FOR
            SELECT 
                I.RENT_NUM, I.DETAIL_DUEDATE, I.DETAIL_RETURNDATE, 
                I.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE, D.DETAIL_DUEDATE, 
                D.DETAIL_RETURNDATE, D.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE
            FROM 
                inserted I 
            INNER JOIN 
                DELETED D ON I.Rent_Num = D.Rent_Num 
                          AND I.Vid_Num = D.Vid_Num

        DECLARE @RENT_NUM INT
        DECLARE @RETURN_DATE_NEW DATETIME
        DECLARE @DUE_DATE_OLD DATETIME
        DECLARE @DUE_DATE_NEW DATETIME
        DECLARE @RETURN_DATE_OLD DATETIME
        DECLARE @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @LATE_FEE_PRIOR DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @LATE_FEE_AFTER DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @CHANGE DECIMAL (5,2)

        OPEN CURSORFORUPDATE 

        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORFORUPDATE INTO @RENT_NUM, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW, @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN

--A
IF(@RETURN_DATE_OLD > @DUE_DATE_OLD)

BEGIN

    SELECT @LATE_FEE_PRIOR = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD) * @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD

    END
    ELSE
        SELECT @LATE_FEE_PRIOR = 0
--B
    IF(@RETURN_DATE_NEW > @DUE_DATE_NEW) 
    BEGIN
    SELECT @LATE_FEE_AFTER = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW) * @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW

    END
    ELSE
        SELECT @LATE_FEE_AFTER = 0

--C
    SELECT @CHANGE = @LATE_FEE_AFTER - @LATE_FEE_PRIOR

--D
    IF(@CHANGE <> 0)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @MEM_NUM INT
    SELECT @MEM_NUM = M.Mem_Num
    FROM RENTAL R INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP M ON R.MEM_NUM = M.MEM_NUM AND R.RENT_NUM = @RENT_NUM

    UPDATE MEMBERSHIP
    SET Mem_Balance = MEM_BALANCE + @CHANGE
    WHERE Mem_Num = @MEM_NUM 

    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORFORUPDATE
    INTO @RENT_NUM, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_OLD, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD

    END
    CLOSE CURSORFORUPDATE
    DEALLOCATE CURSORFORUPDATE

    END
END
END
```

The update I a running is

```
UPDATE DETAILRENTAL
SET DETAIL_RETURNDATE = 2013-03-10
WHERE RENT_NUM = 1001
```

This makes it so that the movie is returned late in the DETAILRENTAL table which should update the member balance in the MEMBERSHIP table.  Any ideas on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added the database tag.  The syntax is obviously SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The `DETAIL_RETURNDATE` field has `datetime` or `date` type, probably, yet you are attempting to set it to a number: 2013-03-10 = 2013 minus 3 minus 10 = 2000.

Try this:

```
Update DETAILRENTAL
   Set DETAIL_RETURNDATE = Convert(datetime, '2013-03-10', 23)
   Where RENT_NUM = 1000;
```

In this case the `Convert(datetime, , 23)` might not be strictly necessary but is good practice if your input dates are in consistent format.

**Edit**

*The former may be the source of your problem, but I also noticed this which is more likely to be what's causing the error*

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_MEM_BALANCE_AWW]
ON [dbo].[DETAILRENTAL]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE CURSORFORUPDATE CURSOR FOR
        SELECT I.RENT_NUM, I.DETAIL_DUEDATE, I.DETAIL_RETURNDATE,I.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE, 
            D.DETAIL_DUEDATE, D.DETAIL_RETURNDATE, D.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE
          FROM inserted I INNER JOIN DELETED D ON I.Rent_Num = D.Rent_Num AND I.Vid_Num = D.Vid_Num

        DECLARE @RENT_NUM INT
        DECLARE @RETURN_DATE_NEW DATETIME
        DECLARE @DUE_DATE_OLD DATETIME
        DECLARE @DUE_DATE_NEW DATETIME
        DECLARE @RETURN_DATE_OLD DATETIME
        DECLARE @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @LATE_FEE_PRIOR DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @LATE_FEE_AFTER DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @CHANGE DECIMAL (5,2)

        OPEN CURSORFORUPDATE 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORFORUPDATE
        INTO @RENT_NUM, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW, 
                @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD

        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            --A
            IF(@RETURN_DATE_OLD > @DUE_DATE_OLD)
                SELECT @LATE_FEE_PRIOR = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD) * @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD;
            ELSE
                SELECT @LATE_FEE_PRIOR = 0;

            --B
            IF(@RETURN_DATE_NEW > @DUE_DATE_NEW) 
                SELECT @LATE_FEE_AFTER = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW) * @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW
            ELSE
                SELECT @LATE_FEE_AFTER = 0

            --C
            SELECT @CHANGE = @LATE_FEE_AFTER - @LATE_FEE_PRIOR

            --D
            IF(@CHANGE <> 0)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @MEM_NUM INT;
                SELECT @MEM_NUM = M.Mem_Num
                  FROM RENTAL R 
                  INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP M ON R.MEM_NUM = M.MEM_NUM AND R.RENT_NUM = @RENT_NUM

                UPDATE MEMBERSHIP
                   SET Mem_Balance = MEM_BALANCE + @CHANGE
                   WHERE Mem_Num = @MEM_NUM 
            END -- End of IF(@CHANGE <> 0)

            FETCH NEXT FROM CURSORFORUPDATE
            INTO @RENT_NUM, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW, 
                @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD
        END  -- End of WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

        CLOSE CURSORFORUPDATE
        DEALLOCATE CURSORFORUPDATE
    END -- End of IF(EXISTS (Select * From Inserted) AND EXISTS (Select * From Deleted))
END -- end of trigger
```

It seems that when you go to fetch from the cursor the second time, the variables that you list are in a different order to the first time. So you're trying to insert from the `DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE` into `@RETURN_DATE_NEW` and from `DETAIL_RETURNDATE` into `@DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW`.

I think there might also have been some issues with matching of `BEGIN ... END`.

**Edit**

Here is my test script, it seems that everything works correctly here.

```
Create Table Rental (
    Rent_Num int,
    Mem_Num int);
Create Table DetailRental (
    Rent_Num int,
    Vid_Num int,
    Detail_DueDate datetime,
    Detail_ReturnDate datetime,
    Detail_DailyLateFee decimal(5,2));
Create Table Membership (
    Mem_Num int,
    Mem_Balance money);

Insert Into Membership Values (1, 0);
Insert Into Rental Values (1, 1);
Insert Into DetailRental 
Values  (1, 1, '2016-11-21', '2016-11-23', 1),
        (1, 2, '2015-11-21', '2016-11-22', 0.5);
Go
```

*Then create the trigger on the table, as per previous listing*

```
Select * From DetailRental;
Select * From Rental;
Select * From Membership;

Update DetailRental
   Set Detail_ReturnDate = '2016-11-21'
   Where Rent_Num = 1;

Select * From Membership;
Go
```

Before

```
Mem_Num  Mem_Balance
1        0.00
```

After

```
Mem_Num  Mem_Balance
1        2.00
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I did the different update statement style first and it did not work.  I then changed the order of the variables in the fetch statements to match each other and tried the update statement again and it still did not work .  I got this error:  "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".  When I tried my update statement the original way I had it I got an error saying ""A cursor with the name "CURSORFORUPDATE" does not exist.  I don't understand how it says it does not exist if it is pulling the name of the cursor from the cursor?

Comment: @AustinWeller Can we continue in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48862/chat-for-conversion-error-in-curosr

Comment: I would not be opposed to it, but my reputation on this site is not high enough to chat apparently

Comment: @AustinWeller Oh, so when you changed the order of the variables in the `FETCH NEXT` you put them in this order: `@RENT_NUM, @DUE_DATE_NEW, @RETURN_DATE_NEW, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_NEW, @DUE_DATE_OLD, @RETURN_DATE_OLD, @DAILY_LATE_FEE_OLD`?

Comment: @AustinWeller Hi, I have reproduced your trigger definition in full with the suggested changes. Can you please try with this new version?

Comment: Just incorporated the reproduced code.  It isnt throwing any errors anymore..... THANK YOU!!!! But now when I do update statements it isn't changing anything in the tables.  So it isn't updating anything.  At first it changed one number for the membership balance to -4 (not sure why) and now, nothing is changing when I update rows.

Comment: @AustinWeller Can you update question with sample data?

Comment: @AustinWeller And I added some scripts which I used for testing. The trigger seems to work for me.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot more sense to test it that way.  I was doing it completely wrong.  Idk why but I got -4 somehow.  I had never seen/written script like that for testing.  I am very new to SQL if you were not able to tell already

Comment: @AustinWeller That's okay, we all were new once. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much @mendosi.  You were super helpful.  Can't thank you enough.